# Generation of negative ions in air

Tags: electric-fields, voltage, air, plasma-physics, ions

What is the main physical mechanism behind the generation of negative ions in air by a high negative voltage electrode ?

Comment: Well, the main mechanism is attaching an electron to a neutral molecule... Can you be a little more specific about what you want to understand? This is a pretty broad question.

Comment: @JonCuster: what is the physical mechanism in order to generate free electrons? I like to understand the physics in order to design an ionizer.

Comment: Field emission from the electrode would be one good bet. And, if you get one free electron in a strong field you likely will get avalanche effects, multiplying the number of free electrons. One search term is 'corona current'.